# antd react get different displays

Tags: reactjs, antd

Having a `antd` with `react`, consider two options to render the `Sider` part.

**Option 1:**
Create CustomSider:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './CustomSider.css';
import { Layout, Menu } from 'antd'
import { Link } from 'dva/router'

const CustomSider = () => {
  return (
    <Layout.Sider>
      <Menu mode="inline" theme="dark">
        <Menu.SubMenu title="Menu">
          <Menu.Item>Submenu</Menu.Item>
        </Menu.SubMenu>
      </Menu>
    </Layout.Sider>
  );
}

export default CustomSider;
```

and use the CustomSider as:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Layout>
    <Layout>
      <CustomSider/>
    </Layout>
  </Layout>
<Content>
  about
</Content>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In this case, the page is rendered as following:

[image]

**Option 2：**
Render the `Sider` directly

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Layout>
    <Layout>
      <Layout.Sider>
        <Menu mode="inline" theme="dark">
          <Menu.SubMenu title="Menu">
            <Menu.Item>Submenu</Menu.Item>
          </Menu.SubMenu>
        </Menu>
      </Layout.Sider>
    </Layout>
  </Layout>
<Content>
  about
</Content>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Then the output is:

[image]

I know that Option 2 renders the page as intended. But what causes the difference? And if I insist using **Option 1**, how can I render the page as **Option 2**.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap `Layout.Sider` with `Layout` and reduce one Layout in the router.